# Checking holomorphy of a function for the Abel-Plana formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I wish to calculate the sum
$$ 
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} f(n) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \left(\alpha^2 n^2 + B^2\right)^s \cos(n \alpha \varepsilon)
$$
using the Abel-Plana sum formula. In principle, I would use
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=j} f(n) = \frac{f(j)}{2} + \int^{\infty}_j f(\tau) d\tau + i \int^{\infty}\frac{dt}{e^{2\pi t}-1} [f(j+i t)-f(j-it)]
$$
with $j=0$ (so the third integral would conveniently go to zero). However, one necessary condition for the formula to be valid is that $g(\tau + it)$ is holomorphic for all $\tau \geq j$, and I've seen some papers where it is said that $j=0$ cannot be used directly since the function $g(\tau + it)$ is not holomorphic for $\tau = 0$.

My question is: is it not holomorphic just for some specific values of $s$? Because I wish to derive with respect to $s$ and set $s=0$ in the end, so maybe that restriction could be bypassed since for $s=0$ the function is holomorphic.